Pregnancy in a hibernated state
In my story, a space ark travels to a new earth on a journey that takes 18 years. The colonists are put in stasis to prevent them aging before they reach their target planet.
One female became pregnant just before stasis.
Assuming stasis (or any equivalent technology) works by slowing down biology, would it be feasible for a pregnancy to last > 2 years? Or is a pregnancy inherently 9 months long, for some reason?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"are put in stasis to prevent aging". In order to do that, cell metabolism must be stopped. No cell metabolism = no growth/cell-reproduction. Could you clarify what the question is?

There are at least a dozen different types of stasis in science fiction. In Farmer's Dayworld series, it's instantly stopping all molecular motion. In Clark's 2001 they use hibernation pods, where biological function is slowed but not completely stopped. Since the technology doesn't exist today, you get to pick how it works in your world.

@Escapeddentalpatient. you're right about that, I sort of envisioned a slowed metabolism rather than a complete freeze, so that the aging process would be delayed rather than slowed.

You need to provide more details about what effect you envisage your 'stasis' system having on the human body i.e. if for instance system somehow (magically) slows down the bodies metabolism, wound healing and reproductive systems etc by a ratio of about 10  then a person would age one year for every 10 spent in stasis, heal 10 times more slowly and it would take 10 times longer for a pregnancy to come to term so 90 months - way before your ark reaches the new world.

They didn't do a final pregnancy test?

Gratefully, pregnancy is not inherently nine months long or dead women would be giving birth to zombie babies!
Gestation is tied to metabolism.[1] From the perspective of strict science: (a) We don't actually know everything there is to know about the human body (not by a LONG SHOT), so my previous statement, despite being backed up with a scholarly article, is the normal "best guess" of science, which leads us to... (b) It's not that simple, but for the purposes of your question, it is... kinda....
Which means if you slow the metabolism down, gestation increases. So if the rule of your world is that a person ages, say, one week for every year in hibernation then after 18 years in hibernation a person has aged only 18 weeks or about four months.
The ratio of age to hibernation time is 100% your choice. Cyronics is a pseudoscience today and a fictional science for all intents and purposes. Whether someone lives or dies is up to you, how slowly they age is up to you, etc. Hallelujah, because if everything were driven by science it wouldn't be worldbuilding, it would be a documentary.
I was hoping to find a cool test of this hypothesis by finding a study about gestation times vs. sleep or unconscious time (because on average human metabolism slows down about 15% when sleeping.[2]). Unfortunately, I couldn't find such a study. But that's OK, the fact that metabolism slows during sleep backs up the idea that metabolism could/would slow a lot during hibernation (right down to zero if you freeze someone all the way through).
Conclusion
Because you set the ratio between aging and hibernation, you can set the gestation period to anything you want and it's rational because of the studies that claim gestation is tied to metabolism and metabolism slows during sleep. In other words, the world rule you're setting is "how deeply" the hibernation process affects the body and the consequences is the gestation period is likewise lengthened.

Offtopic, but this would also make an interesting issue when you ask someone their age. After 10yrs in hiber, are you 10yrs older? Are you now 45 instead of 35? You might need to introduce an term for non-hiber-age

@Martijn I would say no - if you neither physically nor mentally experienced the time, there’s not much different than if we stuck you in a Time Machine and you popped out 10 years later

@Martijn You're right, but I suspect that problem has already been solved in a story that allows flight at a significant fraction of the speed of light. But what might really get your skivies in a twist is the idea that since your metabolism slows by about 15% when you sleep, people who sleep less will live 5-10 years less than people who sleep regularly - because they're aging faster!

@Martijn in the game "Rimworld" characters can have two age values - a biological one (which is used for all practical purposes of age), and a chronological one (which is just for bookkeeping). Of course this requires a universally agreed on reference timeframe to calculate the chronological one in - so it might somewhat work for hibernation, but definitely not for FTL or even close-to-lightspeed travels!

"Which means if you slow the metabolism down, gestation increases" — you meant "gestation decreases", no?

Op needs to qualify what they mean by "stasis". Is it cryonic suspension -  in which the mother and the child are essentially frozen, or hibernation/torpor, where just the metabolism is slowed? If the latter, pregnancy cannot be extended willy-nilly, because the uterine fluid will eventually start fermenting, the placenta will shrivel, and the baby will die. Human pregnancy usually lasts just under 9 months, and these things evolved to barely last that long. Even with slowed metabolism, you cannot have a child marinate in rancid soup.

@GoingDurden Those are great points that the OP should take into consideration. However, it's the fundamental essence of worldbuilding that reality must be simplified to tell a story. If the nature of "stasis" is to slow the aging process (possibly calling that "slowing the metabolism"), then no rancid soup occurs, the uterine fluid (etc.) wouldn't age any faster than any other part of the body. But that's up to the OP. Frankly, incorporating your observations into the story would add texture to the story. Thanks for commenting!

Uterine fluids and placenta can, and often do go bad for a different reason: the child pees, and occasionally craps into it, and then bacteria ferment it. The fluids are continuously renewed but only if the mother's metabolism is working very, very quickly to recycle them. This is an overall problem with hibernation: the bacteria in your body do not hibernate, and keep making stuff rot. You need pretty serious biomods, chemicals or very low temperature to make the bacteria die or become inactive, and by this point this is pretty much cryo anyway.

Chani, are you still with us? @GoingDurden is making some great points.

First things first:
Animals did it. Several species in the animal kingdom have delayed pregnancies or the ability to halt pregnancies.
https://findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/news/8815-some-animals-pause-their-own-pregnancies--but-how-they-do-it-is-still-a-mystery
The problem is that there have to be pathways for that hibernation of pregnancy to rapidly go from the mother to the fetus. Otherwise, the fetus gets starved of oxygen and nutrients, resulting in a stillbirth at revival.
The biggest danger here is obviously oxygen starvation. Sending the mother to sleep without reaching the fetus before her metabolism slows down, would damage it.
If your hibernation includes cooling down, the same measurements that prevent cell death through the formation of ice-crystalls, has to be active in the baby as well at hibernation start. For that it has to traverse or circumvent the blood placenta barrier. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/blood-placenta-barrier
If your hibernation method includes the build up of toxic substances, that have to be flushed out before the hibernation sequence can continue, you should be aware that not only will those poisons build up in the fetus too, but also that some poisons and medicines do damage, depending on how far along the fetus is.
In all fairness, depending on the methods of hibernation- a temporary extraction and seperate freezing of the fetus- with a continued growth in a artifical womb might be easier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_womb
If your flight exceeds nine months, your mother may even choose to restart gestation earlier and wake up to a painless birth from such a machine. This also would remove the strain of the hormonal battle between fetus and  mothers from her body.

When I first saw the question, I thought bears might be a good model for hibernation pregnancy, but it turns out a bear fetus' metabolism doesn't necessarily slow down with the mother's. The options you list look more promising, especially since the process would be designed with human needs in mind.

If she had JUST become pregnant - like 1-5 days, there is a high probability the zygote has not become a blastocyst yet. If the hibernation is chemical - in this case, I don't think anything can be done as there is no connection between the zygote and the body, if the hibernation is chemical/temperature-based, it is a similar case. If the hibernation is magical, however, there are all outcomes possible you can imagine

In that case, extraction and cryogenic storage, similar to embryo freezing nowadays would be the way to go. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryo_cryopreservation

@Pica I am not 100% sure, but I don't think it is possible to detect the conception until the blastocyst binds to the endometrium, hence, you would not know you need to initiate the extraction process. If you do know that you need to - then yes, I am certain that future scientists will find ways to extract the zygote. Otherwise, the embryo is just lost. After the blastocyst binds it is too late for an easy solution :(

If 'just before stasis' is less than a week or so, it may be possible for advanced super space tech to detect and extract the embryo before implantation. After that, the mother could resume pregnancy after the voyage using a process similar to modern frozen embryo transfer. This could avoid medical complications for the baby or mother, if whatever form of stasis you choose would have them.

Equivalent delay, if magic stasis
Stasis is a difficult subject, mostly due to it not being a successful science yet. Especially cryostasis can give a litany of problems. Making things cold can slow down processes in different amounts, or stop others altogether. Take blood for example. Some processes might go much slower, like oxygen transfer. But frozen blood isn't moving, so no further vital oxygen or building materials of the cells are delivered. That means no baby growth. If you solve the blood flowing with some magical non toxic anti-freezing agent, you still need to breathe. These are all very macro problems, as if we look at the cells themselves this can wreak further havock. Stasis due to cryo is right out, unless magic.
If you do use magic cryo, you assume slower processes, so slower growth of a baby. If for example you 'live' a month each year thanks to slow processes, your baby will take about 9 years to complete.
Other stasis
The problem with stasis is that it can be achieved in many ways. For example, you could induce a coma and call it stasis, as there is inactivity in the brain*. That means other processes still occur. Now we have other problems though. The brain is part of an intricate system of hormones. This is probably not good for signalling the right changes during pregnancy, leading to the loss of the baby and possibly the mother. But if you magically induce only a brain stasis that leaves hormones alone (messing with the meaning of stasis further), you would get a baby in 9 months.
This means there is no one answer. Mostly you need to think about what kind of stasis you want, then decide if and how the womb is affected, then apply any magic you want to help the baby and mother to survive that time. Or not, and let the baby and probably the mother die while in stasis.
*not technically true, but close enough

Not sure it's true to say that Stasis due to cryo is right out, unless magic. Cryo is a real thing today, just not in humans but in frogs https://spectrumlocalnews.com/mo/st-louis/weather/2023/01/13/frozen-frogs--the-skill-that-helps-them-survive-the-winter. Obviously would be hard to transfer that to humans, but not magic

We far don't know enough about the human body to hibernate anyone.
Note, only to make you "shut down" for a life-saving operation, requires a doctor specialized only for that, and the general attitude of the healthcare that they hate to do it. What they can do without making you sleep, they do. And that is because some of the patients does not awake.
What is very clear, our body is absolutely not for hibernation. Even if we will be once able to that, it will probably need a very complex machinery; and it will probably take a long time, until the process will be mostly risk-free.
Problem is simple, you can not just stop heartbeat or breathing, because you die. If your brain cells don't get oxygen and sugar, they die in minutes. If they get, they don't turn off and they are aging.
If you cool them, they survive much longer, and if you cool them far below freeze, they could survive infinitely long. But if you cool them below freeze, ice crystals will form and break the cell walls. You again die.
That you can prevent by injecting something into them which prevents the creation of ice crystals. Antifreeze would do that, but it is poisionous and how do you inject it into all the cells?
There are thousands of similar problems to solve, and we are nowhere to do anything with them.
Life functions must be stopped correctly in the correct order with the correct methods, and so should happen also in the other direction.
It is like dismantling a car while you do not stop it.
If the pregnancy itself is not known for the hibernation machinery - and it does not detect that - then the little baby will exist in a mother with ceased life functions. He won't get air. He will be a little angel in the heaven.
